# struts and JSP: how to retain form values on click of some button

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I have created a JSP which has some text and check box fields.And there is a button named as update.
On click of update button I have to update data based on entered values.But the problem is on click of update button I have to redirect to this same page. When I am doing that values that are entered bby the user are not getting reflected instead page is opening with empty values.

Please provide some solution to this problem.

Comment: I dont have a code right now but I just wanted to know how to retain form values.

Comment: If you use Struts as documented, they are kept by default. That's the basis of Struts form validation: you redisplay the form as it was, showing what the validation errors are.

Comment: You said the values aren't being retained; how are you executing this if there's no code or configuration?

Comment: I tried it on some of my colleague's machine and hence I dont have that code...If anybody knows how to do that please let me know. We have defined a <html:form> in jsp and ActionForm class that holds the form values and Action class to execute some logic on click of update button

Comment: We can only guess without seeing the code.

Comment: Just suggest me some solution...how I can prevent the values from getting reset

Answer (score 0):

This is what I believe is one way of doing it. Set the scope in your struts-config.xml file to session.

```
<action path="/helloWorld"
    type="com.HelloWorldAction"
    name="helloWorldForm"
    scope="session" >
    <forward name="success"
        path="tile.helloWorld">
    </forward>
</action>
```